# C++ cstdlib rand tutorial Error

Tags: c++, random

So I have been trying to get a start on programming and I've been following a tutorial that I have found. I have checked my typing multiple times and keep getting the same error "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"   Since I am a newbie I don't understand any of the explanations that I have found online.
           Please help

```
#include <cstdlib>   // Include rand()

using namespace std; // Make rand() visible

int a = rand(); // rand is a standard function that all compilers have
```

[Tutorial link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson4.html)

Comment: The undefined reference to `WinMain` means you are building a GUI application. Try changing your project to a "console" application instead [depending on the IDE, you may have to create a new project to change such settings].

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler/linker thinks you're writing a Windows GUI app, which requires a `WinMain()` function. Try finding the options to create a console app, which expects a function called `main()`. In traditional C/C++ programming, `main()` is the starting point of every program.

The code you've pasted from the tutorial, however, is not a complete C++ program -- it lacks a `main()`. Try the "let's look at an example program" a little farther down, instead.

Finally, C++ is probably the most painful mainstream language to start learning with. Depending on your goals, you may find something like Python to be more enjoyable.